# Trouble with stxnext.staticdeployment in plone 3.3.5

Tags: plone

I'm having trouble in installing [stxnext.staticdeployment](https://github.com/collective/stxnext.staticdeployment) in Plone 3.3.5 on an (outdated) Suse Linux server.

My steps:

1. clean install of Plone 3.3.5 from the [unified unix installer](http://plone.org/products/plone/releases/3.3.5)
2. adding `stxnext.staticdeployment` to `eggs` and `zcml` section as per instructions
3. running `buildout` script
4. starting zope with initial empty plone site

Everything works well except the last step, were I get these run time errors:

```
ERROR Five Could not import Product Products.CMFPlone
ERROR Application Couldn't install Five
```

I'm doing something wrong, or I'm bitten by a bug in stxnext.staticdeployment?

Here is `bin/buildout` output:

```
./bin/buildout 
Updating zope2.
Updating fake eggs
Updating productdistros.
Installing instance.
Updating zopepy.
Updating zopeskel.
Updating chown.
chown: Running chmod 600 .installed.cfg
Updating backup.
Updating unifiedinstaller.
Updating precompile.
  precompiling python scripts in /srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/empty/products
  precompiling python scripts in /srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/empty/parts/productdistros
*************** PICKED VERSIONS ****************
[versions]
BeautifulSoup = 3.2.1
five.globalrequest = 1.0
lxml = 3.2.3
stxnext.staticdeployment = 1.1
zope.globalrequest = 1.0

*************** /PICKED VERSIONS ***************
```

and `instance.log` traceback

```
ERROR Five Could not import Product Products.CMFPlone
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/Zope-2.10.11-final-py2.4/lib/python/Products/Five/fiveconfigure.py", line 76, in loadProducts
    xmlconfig.include(_context, zcml, package=product)
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/Zope-2.10.11-final-py2.4/lib/python/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 515, in include
    processxmlfile(f, context)
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/Zope-2.10.11-final-py2.4/lib/python/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 370, in processxmlfile
    parser.parse(src)
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/Python-2.4/lib/python2.4/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 107, in parse
    xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/Python-2.4/lib/python2.4/xml/sax/xmlreader.py", line 123, in parse
    self.feed(buffer)
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/Python-2.4/lib/python2.4/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 207, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/Python-2.4/lib/python2.4/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 348, in end_element_ns
    self._cont_handler.endElementNS(pair, None)
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/Zope-2.10.11-final-py2.4/lib/python/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 349, in endElementNS
    self.context.end()
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/Zope-2.10.11-final-py2.4/lib/python/zope/configuration/config.py", line 544, in end
    self.stack.pop().finish()
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/Zope-2.10.11-final-py2.4/lib/python/zope/configuration/config.py", line 692, in finish
    actions = self.handler(context, **args)
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/buildout-cache/eggs/z3c.autoinclude-0.3.1-py2.4.egg/z3c/autoinclude/zcml.py", line 104, in includePluginsDirective
    includeZCMLGroup(_context, info, filename)
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/buildout-cache/eggs/z3c.autoinclude-0.3.1-py2.4.egg/z3c/autoinclude/zcml.py", line 30, in includeZCMLGroup
    include(_context, filename, includable_package)
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/Zope-2.10.11-final-py2.4/lib/python/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 515, in include
    processxmlfile(f, context)
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/Zope-2.10.11-final-py2.4/lib/python/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 370, in processxmlfile
    parser.parse(src)
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/Python-2.4/lib/python2.4/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 107, in parse
    xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/Python-2.4/lib/python2.4/xml/sax/xmlreader.py", line 123, in parse
    self.feed(buffer)
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/Python-2.4/lib/python2.4/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 207, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/Python-2.4/lib/python2.4/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 348, in end_element_ns
    self._cont_handler.endElementNS(pair, None)
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/Zope-2.10.11-final-py2.4/lib/python/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 349, in endElementNS
    self.context.end()
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/Zope-2.10.11-final-py2.4/lib/python/zope/configuration/config.py", line 544, in end
    self.stack.pop().finish()
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/Zope-2.10.11-final-py2.4/lib/python/zope/configuration/config.py", line 692, in finish
    actions = self.handler(context, **args)
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/Zope-2.10.11-final-py2.4/lib/python/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 515, in include
    processxmlfile(f, context)
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/Zope-2.10.11-final-py2.4/lib/python/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 370, in processxmlfile
    parser.parse(src)
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/Python-2.4/lib/python2.4/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 107, in parse
    xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/Python-2.4/lib/python2.4/xml/sax/xmlreader.py", line 123, in parse
    self.feed(buffer)
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/Python-2.4/lib/python2.4/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 207, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/Python-2.4/lib/python2.4/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 348, in end_element_ns
    self._cont_handler.endElementNS(pair, None)
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/Zope-2.10.11-final-py2.4/lib/python/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 349, in endElementNS
    self.context.end()
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/Zope-2.10.11-final-py2.4/lib/python/zope/configuration/config.py", line 544, in end
    self.stack.pop().finish()
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/Zope-2.10.11-final-py2.4/lib/python/zope/configuration/config.py", line 691, in finish
    args = toargs(context, *self.argdata)
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/Zope-2.10.11-final-py2.4/lib/python/zope/configuration/config.py", line 1383, in toargs
    args[str(name)] = field.fromUnicode(s)
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/Zope-2.10.11-final-py2.4/lib/python/zope/configuration/fields.py", line 229, in fromUnicode
    v = vt.fromUnicode(s)
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/Zope-2.10.11-final-py2.4/lib/python/zope/configuration/fields.py", line 139, in fromUnicode
    value = self.context.resolve(name)
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/Zope-2.10.11-final-py2.4/lib/python/zope/configuration/config.py", line 184, in resolve
    mod = __import__(mname, *_import_chickens)
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/buildout-cache/eggs/stxnext.staticdeployment-1.1-py2.4.egg/stxnext/staticdeployment/adapters/transformations.py", line 28, in ?
    from plone.app.imaging.interfaces import IImageScaling
ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/buildout-cache/eggs/Plone-3.3.5-py2.4.egg/Products/CMFPlone/configure.zcml", line 116.4-116.60
    ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/buildout-cache/eggs/stxnext.staticdeployment-1.1-py2.4.egg/stxnext/staticdeployment/configure.zcml", line 15.4-15.34
    ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/buildout-cache/eggs/stxnext.staticdeployment-1.1-py2.4.egg/stxnext/staticdeployment/adapters/configure.zcml", line 5.4-10.10
    ImportError: No module named imaging.interfaces
```

and

```
ERROR Application Couldn't install Five
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/Zope-2.10.11-final-py2.4/lib/python/OFS/Application.py", line 786, in install_product
    initmethod(context)
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/Zope-2.10.11-final-py2.4/lib/python/Products/Five/__init__.py", line 28, in initialize
    zcml.load_site()
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/Zope-2.10.11-final-py2.4/lib/python/Products/Five/zcml.py", line 53, in load_site
    _context = xmlconfig.file(file)
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/Zope-2.10.11-final-py2.4/lib/python/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 579, in file
    include(context, name, package)
  File "/srv/pstatic/Plone-3.3.5/Zope-2.10.11-final-py2.4/lib/python/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 517, in include
    assert _context.stack[-1].context is context
AssertionError
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like stxnext.staticdeployment is missing the dependency of plone.app.imaging, which is by default in Plone 4, but in Plone 3.x it needs to be installed explicitely.

I posted this issue here: https://github.com/collective/stxnext.staticdeployment/issues/13
but in order to workaround this problem, just make sure that plone.app.imaging is installed.

Comment: I gave it just a quick try, but I do not think that plone.app.imaging can be easily backported to plone 3. (Just adding the single egg gave rise to other unmet dependencies.)